# static variable in #define directive c++

Tags: c++, static-variables, compiler-directives

Is it possible to declare static variable in a `#define` directive?

```
    // header file
    #define TEXT_ENUM
    #ifdef TEXT_ENUM
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO  \
             static const char * TEXT[]; \
             static const char * getText( int _enum ) { \
                 return TEXT[_enum]; \
             }
    #else
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    #endif

    struct Foo {
        TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    };

   // cpp file
   #include "foo.h"

   const char * Foo::TEXT[] = { 
       "ONE",
       "TWO",
       "THREE",
       0
   };
```

How compiler will resolve static const char *, when I include this header file in some other file and try to access `Foo::TEXT[]`.

Comment: Did you mean `Foo::TEXT[]`? It should work then.

Comment: I get undefined reference to `Packet::TEXT' error.

Comment: @has: That means that your `.cpp` file is missing. In what you provided above `Packet::TEXT` is perfectly defined.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, These files are present in Arduino Library, In arduino code is compiling file.

I need these files in QT project, so what I did is, I add
        INCLUDEPATH += /home/has/Arduino/libraries/
in Qt project file. I did get link to header file. But somehow it is not picking cpp file.

Comment: _@has_ What @AnT said. Also fix your example in the question please!

Comment: i don't know how the qt creator toolchain works precisely (if that's what you are using), but it should be using CMake. Are you sure it is in `set(SOURCE_FILES ...)` ?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, thanks alot,  I had to do both INCLUDEPATH and SOURCE+= filePAth.cpp, to get it working.

Comment: @ANT thanks a lot for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare static variable in a `#define` directive?

Yes, it is possible.

> How compiler will resolve static const char *, when I include this header file in some other file and try to access `Foo::TEXT[]`.

It's resolved at the linking stage.

Comment: If I '#define TEXT_ENUM' in other file  and remove it from this 'foo.h' file, I again get underfined reference error. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: @has That's probably a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to figure out what happens through the stages of compilations that the C compiler uses.

Since #define si a pre-compiler directive, everything will be resolved before actually compiling or looking at the code. Pieces of text (code, functions, whatever is included) will be passed on or filtered according to the directive.

All the rest happens after that, like compilation, that will look for global variable declaration, and linking, that will look for the address of those variable.

In you case, if you take your file and compile with a gcc compiler and the -E option (to do just the precompiler stage), you will get:

```
    struct Foo {
        static const char * TEXT[]; static const char * getText( int _enum ) {   return TEXT[_enum]; }
    };

   const char * Foo::TEXT[] = {
       "ONE",
       "TWO",
       "THREE",
       0
   };
```